# How to write mapreduce program with amazon ec2 and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I want to analyse data stored in amazon s3, how can I write java program on amazon emr and access these data.

The data url is http://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-publicdatasets/trec/kba/FAKBA1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EMR has built-in integration with S3.
There are several guide on how to do it. [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlKndm22bXw)